# Подгрузка данных AJAX'ом

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
var text,
  arr = [],
  div,
  input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keypress', () => {

  const search = () => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

      arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      var previousDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');

      if (previousDiv) {
        for (let i of previousDiv) {
          i.remove();
        }
      }

      if (arr) {

        arr.forEach(i => {

          if (i.includes(input.value)) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = i;
            document.body.appendChild(div);
          }

        });
      }

    }

  };

  return search();
});
```

```html
<input placeholder='Для поиска введите слово'>
```

Попытался реализовать вывод возможных результатов на основе введённой строки.
Нужно ли при каждом изменении строки требовать у сервера передачи всех данных? В данном коде проверка осуществляется после загрузки абсолютно всех значений. Но что, если их будет много? Как запросить у сервера только то, что удовлетворяет условию?

Comment: наверное в Ващем случае искать должен сервер и вернуть найденные строки

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, может, я скажу глупость, но где-то читал, что основной код лучше делать на стороне клиента в целях безопасности. И ещё один вопрос, можно ли уменьшить время ответа сервера? При вводе слова ответ около 1-2 секунд

Comment: ???? безопасно - на сервере.

Comment: если только секретом не является сама поисковая строка, однако этот вариант нагружает сеть. так можно сделать если данные постоянные, но тогда грузить 1 раз

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, а почему у поисковиков нет задержек ? :)

Comment: Поисковики-то точно не выгружают свои индексы на клиент

Comment: Всё впитал, всем спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем грузить файл на каждое изменение инпута?

```
xhr.open('GET', 'phones.json', true);
```

В ответе же каждый раз одно и тоже. Просто загрузите его один раз в самом начале работы, а потом ищите по уже имеющимся данным.

Либо добавьте в запросе условие фильтрации и проводите её на стороне сервера, а не клиента. Трафика будете гонять заметно меньше.

Не ищите сразу, добавьте таймер. Как только пользователь ввёл что-то, запустите таймер. Если пользователь вводит ещё что-то - прибейте таймер и запустите снова. Ищите только если таймер истёк целиком и пользователь больше ничего не вводил. Так вы избавитесь от лишних поисковых запросов в момент медленного написания какой-то длинной поисковой строки.

Когда будете отправлять запрос на сервер, запоминайте искомую строку. Если до ответа сервера пользователь успел поискать ещё что-то, а первый запрос не успел вернуться, то есть риск, что вы будете показывать результат старого запроса даже после ввода новой строки. В коллбеках проверяйте, действительно ли получен ответ на самую последнюю актуальную поисковую строку. Устаревшие отбрасывайте и никак не обрабатывайте.

Answer (score 0):

В твоём примере ты в любом случае получишь всё, что вернет сервер.

Полагаю, это файл `phones.json`; Ты можешь отфильтровать ответ на клиенте, но время ответа сервера всегда будет одинаковым (читай первое предложение).

Полагаю, функцию поиска/фильтрации следует отдать серверу.